# Is it possible to modify Error's constructor so that it includes the context in which the error was thrown?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

Call me insane, but I want all JavaScript errors to expose the context of `this` when they were thrown. Hard to explain in English, easier to explain what I want in code:

```
var Person = function() {
    this.name = 'Chuck';
}

Person.prototype.speak = function() {
    throw new Error('muted!');
    console.log('My name is', this.name);
}

var person = new Person();

try {
    person.speak(); 
}
catch(error) {
    console.log(error.context.name, 'could not speak.');
}
```

Is it possible for me to automatically populate the `error.context` property such that the code above will work? I'm open to any crazy tricks and using the next version of JavaScript or node.js.

Edit: I'd like to do this without using a custom error. This way I can catch any non-custom errors and still have access to `context`.

Comment: You could create your own custom Error constructor, which accepts a parameter for populating a `context` property. Then in your code, it would be like `throw new CustomError(this, 'muted!');`

Answer (score 6):

Simply attach properties to your error before throwing it (maybe wrap it with a nice function):

```
var obj = {
    foo : 'thingonabob',

    ouch : function () {
        var err = new Error();
        err.context = this;
        throw err;
    }
};

try {
    obj.ouch();
}
catch (e) {
    console.error('The darned %s is at it again!', e.context.foo)
}
```

A possible helper function for this:

```
function ContextifiedError (message, context) {
    var err = new Error(message);
    err.context = context;

    return err;
}
```

And then you `throw ContextifiedError('something', this)`

Edit: As @BenjaminGruenbaum points out, the stack trace is off by one when using the helper. If you care, you can write out a longer-but-somewhat-more-correct helper:

```
function ContextifiedError (message, context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.type = 'ContextifiedError';


    Error.call(this, message);
    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
}
ContextifiedError.prototype = Error.prototype;
ContextifiedError.prototype.constructor = ContextifiedError;
```

The `Error.call` is for calling our "father constructor" on ourselves. `Error.captureStackTrace`, on modern browsers, makes sure we have a correct `.stack` property (see [this article](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi) for an explanation). The rest is boilerplate.

And then you can `throw new ContextifiedError('something', this)`.

Comment: The fact you're creating the `new Error` in the constructor means you're capturing the wrong stack trace (one level too down), might want to fix that.